# Prioritize content scripts over local scripts for event handling

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a content script that listens to event `A`.

But on the local page script, another function listens to this event `A` and might stop its propagation.

The point is that event `A` is handled by the local script *before* the content script, so that I cannot always handle it.

How can I reorganize the event propagation?

Comment: An idea could be to listen to `A` on the parent node, but here `A="hashchange"` so that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**If there is some parent node to the listened node**

You can listen to the event for this node.

**If not, i.e. the event is attached to the window (e.g. `hashchange`)**

You can register content script before the page is loaded, using `contentScriptWhen: 'start'` if you are using `pageMod`.

Unfortunately, it seems that is still not possible using `tab.attach` with the current SDK API.